# looking to compare two different directories using the hash values of files within the directories

Tags: shell-script, macos

looking to compare two directories by checking the hashvalues between all the files in each directory and determine if the two directories are == to each other using the sha256 hashvalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare two directories using `hash` functions with commands like:

```
cd dir1; sha256sum * >../hash_file
cd ../dir2; sha256sum -c ../hash_file >/dev/null 2>&1
EXITCODE=$?
```

Exit code 0 mean the files in directories are identical. This may not work very well if you have subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recursively include the contents of every file in the directory in the single hash, you can use `find` to find all normal files, and exec `cat` to concatenate them, and pipe that into `sha256sum` and save it to a file like so:

```bsh
find dir1 -type f -exec cat '{}' + | sha256sum > hash1
find dir2 -type f -exec cat '{}' + | sha256sum > hash2
diff -q hash1 hash2
```

Comment: Note that this would fail (report the wrong result) if `find` finds the files _in different order_ in the two directories, even if all the files are identical between them.

Comment: @Kusalananda I didn't realize `find` wasn't consistent, but it looks like it goes in "file/directory creation order" according to [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/181815/581395). Pretty surprised there isn't a `-sort` flag or something, but I wasn't able to find a good fix for it :(